# Magento Change Tab Order in Edit Product Section

Tags: magento, adminhtml

I want to change order of tabs in edit product section.For example,categories and inventory tab must be swapped.Overriding `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tabs` block doesn't seem to work.

config.xml

```
<config>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <my_module>
                <class>Company_Adminhtml_Block</class>
            </my_module>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <catalog_product_edit_tabs>Company_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tabs</catalog_product_edit_tabs>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
    <global>
</config>
```

I copied `Company_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tabs` into `local` folder and swapped the category and inventory `addTab` code.Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have configured your module correctly. To do this, you can simply call from a controller action.

```
echo get_class(Mage::getBlockSingleton('adminhtml/catalog_product_edit_tabs'));
```

It should return Company_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tabs if you configuration is correct, or Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tabs if your configuration is failed.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Flushing the cache helped.